# An Elvish word for squirrel

Tags: tolkien-elvish, phrase-request

Is there an Elvish word for squirrel?

According to my latest information from Helmut W. Pesch, Das große Elbisch-Buch, Bastei-Lübbe 2009, there is no such word.

My best try is the Quenya word *nornoyaulë* (literally "oak cat", from *norno* "oak" and *yaulë* "cat", formed after a German dialectal word).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### peccuvo

*peccuvo* (Quenya): Squirrel, lit. "nut-hider" [*pec* 'nut' + *kuvo* 'hider']
([source](http://eldamo.org/content/words/word-2725102035.html): Parma Eldalamberon #22 2015).